# Laravel passport 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport, laragon

so im using laravel with passport and i am having issues. when i make a post request to my AuthController@login it is giving me a 500 internal server error. Here is what im working with

Im using laragon with apache server and mysql for enviroment. I can make request to my register route with no issues but my login route keeps failing. Not sure what im missing

This is my AuthController.php

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
        } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        }
        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

This is my variable stored in .env file

```
PASSPORT_LOGIN_ENDPOINT="http://traxit-backend2.test/oauth/token"
PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID=2
PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET=3xlUZVF1fP5fHOQgXAY2Vd7xrIsGjGNRagcMcfU5
```

This is my api routes

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

And this is the log im getting

> 1. GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException->() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:186
> 2. GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->createRejection() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:149
> 3. GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->finishError() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:102
> 4. GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->finish() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php:43
> 5. GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php:28
> 6. GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy->GuzzleHttp\Handler{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php:51
> 7. GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy->GuzzleHttp\Handler{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php:66
> 8. GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php:30
> 9. GuzzleHttp\Middleware->GuzzleHttp{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RedirectMiddleware.php:70
> 10. GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php:60
> 11. GuzzleHttp\Middleware->GuzzleHttp{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerStack.php:67
> 12. GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php:277
> 13. GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php:125
> 14. GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php:131
> 15. GuzzleHttp\Client->request() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php:89
> 16. GuzzleHttp\Client->__call() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\app\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php:22
> 17. App\Http\Controllers\AuthController->login() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
> 18. call_user_func_array() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
> 19. Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:45
> 20. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:212
> 21. Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:169
> 22. Illuminate\Routing\Route->run() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:679
> 23. Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
> 24. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php:41
> 25. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 26. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 27. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php:57
> 28. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 29. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 30. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:104
> 31. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:681
> 32. Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:656
> 33. Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:622
> 34. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:611
> 35. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:176
> 36. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
> 37. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php:36
> 38. Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 39. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 40. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php:57
> 41. Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 42. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 43. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:31
> 44. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 45. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 46. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:31
> 47. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 48. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 49. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php:27
> 50. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 51. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 52. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
> 53. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
> 54. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
> 55. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:104
> 56. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:151
> 57. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
> 58. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle() C:\laragon\www\traxit-backend2\public\index.php:55

Comment: did you find the solution ? having the same issue

Comment: @TrueCode, see my answer below. I had to add the `passport` variables to my `services.php` config file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue to this was that `services.passport` in my `services` config file did not exist. I put this in my `services.php` config file.

```
'passport' => [
        'login_endpoint'  => env('TOKEN_LOGIN_ENDPOINT'),
        'client_id'    => env('TOKEN_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TOKEN_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    ],
```